# Takes time to load another view programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift2

I have a UIViewController through which I want to call a UITableViewController (this table view is actually embedded in a UISplitViewController and UINavigationViewControler). Loading the UITableViewController or the UISplitViewController programatically takes about 4-5 secs everytime approximately. What should I do to reduce the time? The initial UIViewController is basically for login (just in case, I have Swift 2.2 and Xcode 7.3)

Comment: Are you doing any web service call or any data processing task on main thread when your UISplitViewController load?

Comment: Also we can help you when you share your code snippet to get more information.

Comment: i am making API calls to 2-3 PHP scripts. I am new to swift, please elaborate your question, if this is not the answer to your question

Comment: In that case you need to call your 2-3 PHP scripts in background thread and when you received a response then update your ui on main thread. It will resolve your problem.

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you :)

Comment: As your problem is resolved with above approach then accept my answer to help others. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your description you calling web service call on view load. So you need to **call PHP Scripts in background thread**.

When you received a response from PHP Scripts perform **UI updates on Main Thread**.

Thanks.